# How to prevent shutdown race conditions with Qt Network classes

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

We have an OS X C++ application, using Qt 5.5 that provides a simple HTTP server interface.  It's essentially similar to the Fortune Server example provided by Qt (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html), but what we're seeing is that occasionally the application is seg faulting upon shutdown, with the following stack trace (thread 6 crashing):

```
Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8deb4fca __open + 10

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8deb6232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90f0426e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8deb594a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff887833dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8deb594a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff887833dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8deb594a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff887833dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.airportd
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8923378d _os_lock_handoff_lock + 23
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff83258906 objc_object::sidetable_clearDeallocating() + 64
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8323e651 objc_destructInstance + 145
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8323e595 object_dispose + 22
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84eea448 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8325889c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff85747909 -[_NSXPCInterfaceMethodInfo dealloc] + 63
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8325889c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ed5db0 CFRelease + 304
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ee5b92 __CFBasicHashDrain + 498
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff84ed5e8e CFRelease + 526
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8578dd7a -[NSXPCInterface dealloc] + 28
12  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8325889c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8578df0c -[NSXPCConnection dealloc] + 281
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8325889c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
15  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00007fff8d3166e5 _Block_release + 196
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90effe73 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90f035cd _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90f03030 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90f02bef _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90f02a1c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88785a9d _pthread_wqthread + 729
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff887833dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6 Crashed:: Qt bearer thread
0   org.qt-project.QtNetwork        0x0000000100a541cb QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate::~QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate() + 107
1   org.qt-project.QtNetwork        0x0000000100a5431e QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate::~QNetworkConfigurationManagerPrivate() + 14
2   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100d72427 QObject::event(QEvent*) + 823
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100d49588 QCoreApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 104
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100d4a212 QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) + 1058
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100d997db QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 59
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100d46c1c QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 412
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100b9c07e QThread::exec() + 110
8   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000100b9fc02 QThreadPrivate::start(void*) + 338
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8878605a _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88785fd7 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff887833ed thread_start + 13
```

As you can see, thread 0 is done - we're outside main.  I'm sure there's some cleanup code I'm failing to call when we're disposing of our resources, but I don't know what it can be.

Without putting all our source up here, the basic chain of calls were doing is:

```
class RestServer : public QObject {
RestServer::RestServer() {
    _tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
}

void RestServer::listen(quint16 port)
{
    if (!_tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost, port)) {
        LOG_ERROR("RestServer", "Failed to start server at: " << port);
        throw std::exception();
    }
    _portNum = _tcpServer->serverPort();
    LOG_INFO("RestServer", "Server is listening at: " << _portNum);
    connect(_tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(connectSocket()));
}
```

Then in our test code, we basically do:

```
void RestAPIServer_test::responseCallback(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
  auto response = reply->readAll();
  _uri = response;

  reply->close();

  QCoreApplication::exit();
}

TEST_F(RestAPIServer_test, urlWithPercents)
{
  RestServer restServer();
  restServer.listen(0);
  quint16 port = restServer.serverPort();

  // "widget/foo bar.txt"
  QUrl serviceUrl(QString("http://localhost:%1/path/?path=widget%2Ffoo%20bar.txt").arg(port));

  QNetworkAccessManager networkManager(this);
  connect(&networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(responseCallback(QNetworkReply*)));

  QNetworkRequest request(serviceUrl);
  request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  networkManager.get(request);

  QCoreApplication::exec();

  ASSERT_EQ(QString("path=widget/foo bar.txt"), _uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be due to some networking-related threads created by Qt still running for a bit after the call to QCoreApplication::quit() was called, probably because the quit() was called from within the callback function registered with the QTcpSocket.  The solution was to put a 1-second sleep after the call to exit:

```
void RestAPIServer_test::responseCallback(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    auto response = reply->readAll();
    _uri = response;

    reply->close();

    QCoreApplication::exit();

    // This prevents a shutdown race condition where Qt service
    // threads continue to run after the call to exit().
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to instantiate a `QObject` on stack with a parent. Look at the line

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkManager(this);
```

The object would be destroyed twice, which is not possible, so you see the crash. Change that line as follows (of course, the use of variable `networkManager` must also be updated):

```
QNetworkAccessManager* networkManager=new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Actually, a previous version of this example was doing just what you said, but I changed it to a stack variable in this case to see if the problem was due to networkManager living beyond the scope of this code.  In either case, the occasional segfault occurs.

Comment: How do you call `quit()` on the `QCoreApplication` to stop the `exec()` loop? I would suggest that you insert a proxy slot there between your signal and `quit()` in which you could try to destroy your server and network access manager explicitly. Then you could promote the signal to `quit()` slot either directly or using `QTimer::singleShot()` to ensure that all network threads are finished correctly. See what result you'll get.

Comment: "It is not safe to instantiate a QObject on stack with a parent.” - that’s only true if the parent can possibly be deleted before the object on the stack. Otherwise the object is removed from the parent’s list of children when destroyed, thus no double-deletion.

Comment: @EvgenyS. : The responseCallback function calls QCoreApplication::quit.  I left it out of the example above, but I'll edit my question to include it.

Comment: @EvgenyS.: With my edits, can you explain a bit what you mean by a "proxy slot"?